# align numbers based on first digits (not minus signs)

Tags: emacs

How do i align this so minus sign stay outside of aligned columns:

```
{
    0.0f, -1.0f, -2.2f,
    -1.1f, 0.0f, -100.0f,
    -3.32f, -5.1f, 0.0f
}
```

like so:

```
{
     0.0f,  -1.0f, -2.2f,
    -1.1f,   0.0f, -100.0f,
    -3.32f, -5.1f,  0.0f
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer:

<kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd> `align-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\(\s-*-?\)[0-9.]+` <kbd>RET</kbd> `-1` <kbd>RET</kbd> `1` <kbd>RET</kbd> `y` <kbd>RET</kbd>

or you can make a rule for C and C-like modes:

```
(eval-after-load "align"
 '(add-to-list 'align-rules-list
               '(c-align-decimals
                  (regexp . "\\(\\s-*-?\\)[0-9.]+")
              (group . (1))
              (spacing . 1)
              (justify . 1)
              (repeat . t)
              (modes quote(c-mode c-common-mode)))))
```